# My script works only for the first class

Tags: javascript, jquery

it's work only for first `.circle` class
I have 5 `.circle`

```
$(this).find('.circle').click(function(){
    var margin = parseInt($(this).css("left"), 10)-40;
    var plan = parseInt($('.move_plane').css("left"), 10);

    if( margin > plan ){
        $('.move_plane').attr("src", "img/icon/move_plane.png");
    }
    else{
        $('.move_plane').attr("src", "img/icon/move_plane_back.png");
    }
});
```

`$('.move_plane').attr("src", "img/icon/move_plane_back.png");` = [image]
when I clicked

[image]

The plane moves to the second circle like it should, but when I click on the other circles the plane should rotate and back clicked position, when circle rotate back first location rotate works fine but when back second or third or forth circle plane don't rotate back

```
<div class="icon_div"> 
    <img class="move_plane" src="img/icon/move_plane.png"/> 
    <img class="fi_circle circle" src="img/icon/circle.png"/> 
    <img class="first_circle circle" src="img/icon/circle.png"/> 
    <img class="second_circle circle" src="img/icon/circle.png"/> 
    <img class="third_circle circle" src="img/icon/circle.png"/> 
    <img class="last_circle circle" src="img/icon/circle.png"/> 
</div>
```

Comment: could you provide us with a jsfiddle for better help ?

Comment: What does your HTML look like? And what is `$(this)`?

Comment: As @putvande pointed out, what is `$(this)` probably is that the problem ( using the wrong pointer... )

Comment: What you want is to compare the current plane position and its destination to choose between the normal and back icons. Could you provide the piece of code where you do that ?

Comment: Post your HTML, Whats `this` in `$(this).find('.circle')`

Comment: @valkharitonashvili Edit the question with the HTML, or use jsfiddle.net (easier) =)

Comment: You still need to show us where you add the script. What is $(this)? If you append it to only a part of the page, of course it will only fire with one of the circles.

Comment: hey I have team viewer if you can help me I show you what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?
[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aw0v1crs/)

This uses jQuery's [`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) function, you might want to change this as I don't know the rest of your HTML/CSS code.

Hope it helps to fix your problem.